# Running Tests in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, python, testing, helm

We have code that deploys new kubernetes clusters with core infrastructure services like cert-manager, external-dns, load balancer controllers etc in a cloud environment. We provision these with the intent that others in the organization can quickly spin up new cluster while conforming to standards set by security, IT, and so on.

After deploying our cluster and services using helm charts, we don't run any tests to verify the usability of our infrastructure. For example, testing the aforementioned services actually function.

I'm curious how others are approaching this kind of testing. What test suites are you using? Do you have any recommendations/suggestions?

I was leaning towards python test framework in https://github.com/vapor-ware/kubetest. however, I've since noticed that there have been no contributions to the project for several years.